# Instrumenting Akka FSM

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

I like to take the metrics a FSM needs till it reaches a certain state.
Instead of spamming my classes with metrics code I would like to add a trait which overrides certain methods and emits a message when the method is called.

For example:

```
trait InstrumentedActorFSM[S,D] extends Actor with FSM[S,D] {self: Actor with FSM[S,D] with Logging  =>
  startTimer // start measuring time here with Graphite

  override def stop = {
    stopTimerAndEmitMessage // emit message to graphite
    super.stop
  }
}
```

Sadly all methods whitin FSM are declared final and can't be overwritten. I could resort to the Cake pattern and embed a FSM an reimplement all calls but that feels quite clumsy. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use onTransition handler like:

```
trait InstrumentedActorFSM[S,D] extends Actor with FSM[S,D] { ...

  onTransition {
    case _ -> SomeState => stopTimerAndEmitMessage
  }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me as I will not be able to use onTransition for anything else then.

Comment: From akka docs: Multiple such blocks are supported and all of them will be called, not only  the first matching one.

Comment: Exactly - you can have multiple onTransition blocks registered.

Comment: Cool thanks I didn't know that. Is that also true for 'startWith' and 'stop' ?

Comment: The better way to find the answer is lo look at FSM.scala sources. So multiple stop and startWith calls would just overwrite previous FSM state.